# Large JSON Data not shown in console

Tags: json, node.js

I am using node.js and created a module to fetch data from the sql server database. The data is retreived as JSON. 
Here is the code

**b.js**

```
var mssql = require('mssql');

var config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'scott',
    server: 'MSSQL2008',
    database: 'AdventureWorks',
    stream: false
};

var msconnection = new mssql.Connection(config, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});

        module.exports.getCustomersDetails = function (callback, id) {
            var request = new mssql.Request(msconnection);

            //Add Parameters to the SP 
            if (id != null) {
                request.input('ID', id);
            }

            request.execute('CUSTOMER_DETAILS_GET', function (err, recordsets, returnValue) {  // get data
                if (err) console.log(err);

                responseContent = {
                    recordDataKey: 'data',
                    data: recordsets[0]
                };
                callback(responseContent);
            });
        };
```

**a.js**

```
var c = require('./b.js');
c.getCustomersDetails(function (responsecontent) {
    console.log(responsecontent);
},  '101,202,303,505,808, 100, 200, 300, 400');
```

When I run a.js the console shows nothing and that's because there are lot of records in the table.
Can anybody suggest how can I get all the records? Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: I have 25 columns in one row so it is bringing me top 140 records but when I write get me top 150 or all in SP then it does not show anything in the console.

**Update:**
can anybody help me and suggest how we can do streaming in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronicity is back to bite you!

```
var c = require('./b.js');
// start loading the db
// it's not ready yet when you call the function!
c.getCustomersDetails(function (responsecontent) {
console.log(responsecontent);
},  '101,202,303,505,808, 100, 200, 300, 400');
```

You'll need to rewrite your module to use an initialization function and callback. I would do something like:

```
c.init(function(){
    c.getCustomersDetails(); // ...
});
```

and

```
var msconnection;
exports.init = function(callback){
    msconnection = new mssql.Connection(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        callback();
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Scimonster for the reply.the code above gives me result when there are few records say 100 but when the total record count exceeds to say 6000 it does not show anything.

Comment: As i said (in code comments), the DB hasn't loaded yet when you call the `getCustomersDetails` function, which is why you need a callback.

Comment: yes and I have used the callback and it is returning all the values is JSON is small but once there is lot of data it breaks.

Comment: You're using a callback to wait until the database has loaded? In other words, you need to use the callback in `new mssql.Connection`.

Comment: I have tried yourb solution Scimonster but it too did not show the results. As said it is 25 column row and there are billions of rows so the request.execute method code breaks and does not show any results.